# Write a SQL query to find and display a customer who made 2 consecutive orders in same category?

Tags: mysql, sql

Question: Write a SQL query to find and display a customer who made 2 consecutive orders in the same category?

I am struggling with the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Queries:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    item TEXT,
    price REAL,
    ORDER_DATE DATETIME,
    category TEXT);

INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Doctor Who", "doctorwho@timelords.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Harry Potter", "harry@potter.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Captain Awesome", "captain@awesome.com");

INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price,ORDER_DATE,category)
    VALUES (1, "Sonic Screwdriver", 1000.00,'21-04-15 09.00.00','tools');
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price,ORDER_DATE,category)
    VALUES (1, "Light", 1000.00,'21-10-15 09.00.00','tools');
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price,ORDER_DATE,category)
    VALUES (2, "High Quality Broomstick", 40.00,'20-12-20 09.00.00','cleaner');
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price,ORDER_DATE,category)
    VALUES (3, "TARDIS", 1000000.00,'21-01-20 09.00.00','other');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

**Step: 1**

First of all, you add a foreign key in the column containing the customer id of the order table, then after that add the customers and orders tables together.

**Step: 2**

After adding both tables together run this query and you will get your result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.category , customers.id,customers.name,customers.email FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.id= orders.customer_id WHERE orders.category in ( select category from orders group by category having count(*) >= 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it by using LEAD. Get lead_category and lead_customers_id and filter with category, customers_id

```
select * from
(SELECT orders.category , orders.item, customers.id,customers.name,customers.email,
LEAD(category) OVER (ORDER BY customers.id ASC) AS lead_category,
LEAD(customers.id) OVER (ORDER BY customers.id ASC) AS lead_customers_id
FROM orders 
JOIN 
 customers ON 
orders.customer_id = customers.id) AS T
where category = lead_category and id = lead_customers_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer_id
FROM orders t1
JOIN orders t2 USING (customer_id, category)
WHERE t1.ORDER_DATE < t2.ORDER_DATE
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM orders t3
                   WHERE t1.customer_id = t3.customer_id
                     AND t1.category != t3.category
                     AND t1.ORDER_DATE < t3.ORDER_DATE
                     AND t3.ORDER_DATE < t2.ORDER_DATE )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a26be6164e027b1a4b0aa9a736764da3

I.e. we simply search for a pair of orders for the same customer and category where an order with the same customer but another category not exists between these orders.

Join `customers` table if needed.